# SQL select rows with combination of other rows parameters

Tags: sql, firebird

I have table with first column as ID (not unique) and only one parameter in second column. There can be more rows with the same ID and different parameter and I need to select ID with logical combination of parameters

For example select only ID for which there is a parameter "A" and ("B" or "C") or at least select only ID with parameters "A" and "B".

DB is in Firebird, but it is no problem to convert it to MySQL if there is no other way.

Edit:

Table:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID + PARAMETER |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         A |
|  1 |         B |
|  2 |         B |
|  3 |         A |
|  3 |         C |
+----------------+
```

I need to get each ID which have PARAMETER A and B = ID 1 or ID with PARAMETER A and (B or C) = ID 1,3

is it clear now?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31227588/edit) and add the code that you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean with _"ID for which there is a parameter "A" and ("B" or "C")"_. As it stands it is unclear if you simply don't know that you can combine multiple conditions in a `WHERE`-clause using `AND` and `OR`, or if you need a more complex check on something. I'd suggest you post some example data and expected result with an explanation why something should or should not be part of the result.

Comment: show some data, then only we can understand your problem

Comment: And I dont try any usefull code, because I dokt know, how can I do it... something like SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE WHERE PARAMETER=A AND (PARAMETER=B OR PARAMETER=C); but this of course cannot do the task...

Comment: "A and B" or "A and (B or C)" are only examples... I need method, that is usable for more combinations without writing separate query (query will be generated in PHP) only with change of WHERE part.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL devs seem to hate subqueries but it's really the proper way to do this. I may not have gotten the conditions exactly as you require them but it should be close. And I think the A and B condition is redundant with A and (B or C).

```
select distinct ID
from T t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from T t2
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    group by t2.ID
    having
            count(case when t2.parameter = 'A' then 1 else null end) > 0
        and count(case when t2.parameter in ('B', 'C') then 1 else null end) > 0
)
```

Since A is required in all cases then you might find a performance improvement in doing it this way but it's a little less generic.

```
select distinct ID
from T t1
where t1.parameter = 'A' and exists (
    select 1
    from T t2
    where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.parameter in ('B', 'C')
)
```

Comment: P.S. In case it wasn't clear, I wasn't taking a dig at MySQL developers. I just hear over and over again that subqueries don't perform well even though in queries like the above they are very easy to transform into a join.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting to MySQL.
After creating a view

```
CREATE VIEW ParameterList AS
  SELECT
    id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT parameter ORDER BY parameter SEPARATOR ',') pList
  FROM SomeTable
  GROUP BY id
;
```

you could:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM ParameterList
WHERE pList = 'A,B'
;

SELECT
  id
FROM ParameterList
WHERE pList IN ('A,B', 'A,C')
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d747/1).

You need, of course, to be strict in formulating your queries: The to be checked for items must be arranged in line with the view's
`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT parameter ORDER BY parameter SEPARATOR ',')`
regarding both `ORDER` and `SEPARATOR`.

Please comment, if and as this does require adjustment / further detail.

Comment: I think that would not work: say there is an ID with parameters `A`, `B` and `C`, then the `pList` would be `A,B,C`. Now query for parameter combination `A and C`

Comment: @ain My response is based on the information given so far. I understand the respective query to be for `AND`, and would return the **id** for `A AND B AND C` as in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c927e/1). Feel free to adjust the Fiddle to illustrate your point.

Comment: Run `SELECT
  id
FROM ParameterList
WHERE pList = 'A,C'
;` in your fiddle - it would return only one row, id = 3, while I quess the OP would want the ID = 1 to be returned too.

Comment: @ain From your perspective, the record should be returned, because **A** and **C** are related to **1**. I do not return it, because there is another parameter (**B**) related to it as well. (Somehow similar to the difference between **OR** and **XOR**...) Which reading is correct from OP's perspective, I can't tell, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I quess you could just join the table to itself using ID, "once per condition", ie to get IDs which have PARAMETER A and B:

```
SELECT distinct a.ID
FROM tab a
join tab b on(a.id = b.id)
where a.PARAMETER = 'A' and b.PARAMETER = 'B'
```

To get IDs with PARAMETER A and (B or C)

```
SELECT distinct a.ID
FROM tab a
join tab b on(a.id = b.id)
where a.PARAMETER = 'A' and (b.PARAMETER = 'B' or b.PARAMETER = 'C')
```